# I am transit passenger and turkish airline will provide hotel, how much time it takes to get visa at the airport?

Tags: air-travel

1. Is it too long line for transit passenger to get visa (Turkish airline and I am canadian)?
2. Is there any pharmacy inside Istanbul airport to buy medicine?

Comment: If you have another passport besides Canadian you might want to use that instead; the visa fee may be lower.

Answer (score 1):

1) If you apply for an E-visa online before you fly, you will be able to join the immigration queue immediately:
. https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/

2) Pharmacy - Günay Eczanesi. Location: International Terminal, landside, Arrivals.
https://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/istanbul.htm

This was a question for Google. Not Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

From the airport perspective you are not a transit passenger if you are intending to go to a hotel, you are an arriving passenger.  This is important because if you were a transit passenger you would not need a visa, however as an arriving passenger you do.

For Canadian citizens you can either obtain an e-visa in advance by going to https://www.evisa.gov.tr (cost US$60) or you can obtain a visa on arrival (cost US$70).  The visa-on-arrival option requires you to first go to a separate area to obtain/pay for your visa, and then return to the normal arrivals immigration queue.

The line at the visa on arrival queue is generally fairly short, but the lines at immigration itself are frequently very long, so even if it only takes 5 minutes to obtain your visa, that could easily add 20+ minutes to your total time due to you joining the immigration queue later. For this reason (plus the lower cost) getting an e-visa in advance would be strongly recommended!

Once you pass through immigration and collect your bags, you will proceed to the Turkish Airlines Hotel counter (turn right and head towards Starbucks - it's about 20 metres before it on the right).  Keep in mind that it could take a further 30+ minutes or more to arrange the hotel and then wait for the shuttle.

And yes, there is a pharmacy *landside* at Istanbul Ataturk airport.  It is located on the departure level, so you will need to go from the arrivals level up to the departure level, then back to the arrivals level to get to the hotel desk.  (Do NOT try and go to the hotel desk first as you will likely miss the shuttle bus they arrange for you to the hotel)

Comment: This answer is so natural it makes you feel like you’re there and going through this process. +1

Comment: @HankyPanky That's probably because I have been there and been through that process multiple times :)